# AndroidStudio and Kotlin: What is Error Expecting Member Declaration

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm learning myself some android programming (beginning level) and following a tutorial. I'm getting an error when I run/build the project. `Expecting member declaration`.  I've checked the code for typos and syntax errors.  I've googled this, but I'm just not sure what it means or what to look for to fix it.

Are other classes used in the project automatically seen by the MainActivity class?

Code in part:

```
MainActivity.kt:

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    val friendlyDestroyer = Destroyer("Invincible")
    val friendlyCarrier = Carrier("Indomitable")

    val enemyDestroyer = Destroyer("Grey Death")
    val enemyCarrier = Carrier("Big Grey Death")

    val friendlyShipyard = ShipYard()

    friendlyDestroyer.takeDamage(enemyDestroyer.shootShell())
    friendlyDestroyer.takeDamage(enemyCarrier.launchAerialAttack())

    // Fight back
    enemyCarrier.takeDamage(friendlyCarrier.launchAerialAttack())
    enemyCarrier.takeDamage(friendlyDestroyer.shootShell())
    ...
```

Any line that has an instance to a class with a function call shows the `red squiggly line` and the error.

In the line: `friendlyDestroyer.takeDamage(enemyDestroyer.shootShell())`, it shows the `expecting member declaration` error at just about every part of the line.

This happens on every instance of a class making a call to a class.

I'm not seeing any errors for the other classes/files.

```
Destroyer.kt:

package com.johndcowan.basicclasses

class Destroyer(name: String) {
    // what is the name of the ship
    var name: String = ""
        private set

    // what type of ship is it
    // alwys a destroyer
    val type = "Destroyer"

    // how much the ship can take before sinking
    private var hullIntegrity = 200

    // how many shots left in the arsenal
    var ammo = 1
      // cannot be directly set externally
      private set

    // no external access whatsoever
    private var shotPower = 60

    // has the ship been sunk
    private var sunk = false

    // this code runs as the instance is being initialized
    init {
        // so we can use the name parameter
        this.name = "$type $name"
    }

    fun takeDamage(damageTaken: Int) {
        if (!sunk) {
            hullIntegrity -= damageTaken
            println("$name hull integrity = $hullIntegrity")

            if (hullIntegrity <= 0){
                println("Destroyer $name has been sunk")
                sunk = true
            }
        } else {
            // Already sunk
            println("Error Ship does not exist")
        }
    }

    fun shootShell():Int {
        // let the calling code know how much damage to do
        return if (ammo > 0) {
            ammo--
            shotPower
        }else{
            0
        }
    }

...
```

What am I missing or not seeing?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: in your `imports` at the top of `MainActivity` I don't see your `Destroyer.kt` file. Check if you have that imported

Comment: Also, your code is inside class `MainActivity` when it should in fact be inside of `onCreate` method or any other method that you need to override

Comment: You cannot write statements inside class, they must be encapsulated in a function, how do you expect them to be at there? Probably you want to put them in the entry point (in this case onCreate).

Comment: Thank you!!  This is what I needed.  What is the syntax for importing a class?  `import Destroyer.kt`  ?